# UTF-16 Encoding

Tags: java, xml, utf-16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <note>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <to>ALOK</to>
        <message>AshuTosh</message>
    </note>
```

I have the XML parser which supports UTF-8 encoding only else it gives SAX parser exception. How can  i convert the UTF-16 to UTF-8?

Comment: There is a 100% chance that your parser supports UTF-18. Give us the name of the parser, the version and the error message to help.

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks for showing the interest i have got the solution of the problem by the answer provided by Jörn Horstmann .........anyways the name of the parser is com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.dom.DOMDocumentParser

Comment: That parser definitely supports UTF-16. Make 100% sure that your documents are proper UTF-16 and that you use the correct APIs.

Comment: @Maksud_Tiger: Please give back to the community and *accept* the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case its not a XML parser that your are using, see [section 2.2 of the xml specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets):

> All XML processors MUST accept the UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings of Unicode

Java xml parsers usually receive their input wrapped in an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) object. This can be constructed with a `Reader` parameter that does the character decoding for the given charset.

```
InputStream in = ...
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-16"));
```

For the "utf-16" [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/Charset.html) the stream should start with a byte order mark, if that is not the case use either "utf-16le" or "utf-16be".

Comment: :-/ The parser should read the XML header (which contains the encoding) and use the rules mentioned above to process the document correctly. You should never define an encoding yourself when reading XML because that will break if someone sends you something using a different encoding.